# Runnable jar file creation - resource folder included in the jar package

Tags: java, jar

my class file i have included a resource folder and read the file and proceed

[image]

question
while creating a jar file i want to included the resource folder (along with file) in the jar package

[image]

purpose
becasue more than one user executing the jar file, they may change the file content and executed

let me know how the resource folder included in the Jar package

Comment: @Rahman : yes added in the class path, but not getting the resource folder, getting only the Lib files

Comment: Users can't change the content of a resource. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP: i have to pass this jar file to some other people they replace the excel file and executed the jar

Comment: They replace the Excel file inside the JAR before executing it? So why are you putting the file inside the JAR at all? Let them do it. It seems to be their Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the resources folder under the `src` folder, that way it will be included in your Runnable Jar.

The correct way to reference a resource file would be to use either [getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) or [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

For example:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/filename.extension");
```

Where "resources" is the name of the folder you placed under `src`.

Comment: Thanks , added the resources under the src, but same exporting resource folder (along with file) not appearing

Comment: I've reviewed your question. It appear you don't want it to be included within the jar, but you want it to sit separately alongside the jar, which is impossible to do automatically. The only way you could do it is by placing the resources folder next to the jar. Package them together in a zip and have people unzip it and change the resources (move it out of the `src` folder in that case!)

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to include the resource files separately within the jar by using a build tool like Maven or gradle.

For example in maven we can do as below:

```
<build>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>ExpirationDates.xlxs</include>
        </includes>
        <!-- relative to target/classes
             i.e. ${project.build.outputDirectory} -->
        <targetPath>..</targetPath>
    </resource>
</resources>
</build>
```